# How to apply cuda-memcheck to an app with piped inputs from standard I/O

Tags: shell, cuda, pipe, openacc

I want to use cuda-memcheck for an app with standard I/O.

The app, dut, reads standard Input and writes standard Output.

```
cat input.txt | cuda-memcheck ./dut -dutoptions > output.txt
```

In this case, the dut app seems to be launched, but cuda-memcheck doesn’t work well.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible method:

Place your command to be executed into a script.  Run cuda-memcheck on that script.

```
$ cat input.txt
4

$ cat t2030.cu
#include <iostream>

__global__ void k(int *d){
  *d = 5;
}

int main(){

  int *d = NULL;
#ifndef FAULT
  cudaMalloc(&d, sizeof(d[0]));
#endif
  int a;
  std::cin  >> a;
  std::cout << "value read: " << a << std::endl;
  k<<<1,1>>>(d);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

$ nvcc -o t2030 t2030.cu
$ cat test
cat input.txt | ./t2030 > output.txt
$ chmod +x test
$ cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ cat output.txt
value read: 4
$ nvcc -DFAULT -o t2030 t2030.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
=========     at 0x00000050 in k(int*)
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x00000000 is out of bounds
=========     Device Frame:k(int*) (k(int*) : 0x50)
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 [0x20d6ea]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x864b]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x5ec88]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3ea0]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3d81]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3da9]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3c2a]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b15]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3a91]
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 719) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libcuda.so.1 [0x3bd253]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3a047]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3c2f]
=========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b15]
=========     Host Frame:./t2030 [0x3a91]
=========
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
$
```

note that for a volta or newer device, `cuda-memcheck` should be replaced by `compute-sanitizer`.

Comment: Hi Robert. Thanks for your reply. It gets work well.